# Is there any way I can use interface created in virtual machine on my host machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, vpn, virtualization

So basically I use gentoo on my host machine, and I have windows 10 virtual machine, in which I created virtual network (using RadminVPN). And what I want to do is to make my host machine use this virtual network. Is there any way I can do this?

Feel free to ask for more info in comments, also I will be thankful for any ideas.

Comment: There is no Radmin VPN for Linux (I use Radmin Tools for Windows).  You would need to research a Radmin VPN compliant alternative if there is on.

Comment: Ye I know. The thing is all my friends use RadminVPN, but I am not comfortable with using windows as my daily driver. I am fairly tech savy so I am not afraid to play with it a little bit. My idea is to use vritual network, created inside of virtualbox windows 10 machine and somehow forward/use it on my real one. I am just not sure if that kind of forwarding network interface is even possible, but I feel like it could be. @John

Comment: Use Bridged Networking for your Host Machine VPN setup and give your Windows 10 machine a static IP on the Host Router.

Comment: Well it worked... kind of. I am not sure if I am missing something but it doesn't work as I intented. I currently have my windows 10 VM with 3 network interfaces:
1. Radmin VPN
2. NAT (that provides internet connection from my gentoo machine)
3. Ethernet 2 - which connects windows 10 VM to my LAN.
And it works, i can ping windows 10 VM from anywhere in my LAN

Comment: But what I wanted to do, is to make my gentoo see Radmin VPN interface, on it's own. I thinked about using redirection with /etc/hosts (to redirect all traffic from Ethernet 2 LAN to RadminVPN interface), but since it's windows on VM machine I am not sure if there's any way to do it @John

Comment: I spent some time with this and do not see any ready way to use Gentoo for this. It has been a long time since I used Gentoo but even looking at newer stuff, I do not see a way.

Comment: Well I don't think I have problem with installing anything on gentoo, I am really familiar with it on itself. So if you can think of any solution that could work on other distro, that would be helpful for me as well. Simply forget I am using gentoo and think of me as let's say debian user. @John